# proving a set has a maximal member

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a nonempty set such that for every set $B$, $B \in A$ iff every finite subset of $B$ is a member of $A$. Prove that $A$ has a maximal member.

I am trying to prove it using Zorn's lemma; so taking a chain like $\mathscr{B}\subseteq A$ I want to show that $\cup \mathscr{B} \in A$ but I'm not sure how "every finite subset of $B$ is a member of $A$" comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any finite subset $B \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr B$.  Then because $\mathscr B$ is a chain there is some $X \in \mathscr B \subseteq A$ such that $B \subseteq X \in A$.

To see this, note that each element of $X$ is an element of some member of $\mathscr B$ and since $X$ is finite, that means we only need finitely many members of $\mathscr B$ to capture all of $X$.  Since $\mathscr B$ is a chain, these finitely many members have a largest member, which necessarily captures all elements of $B$; in other words, $B \subseteq X$.

Thus, $B \in A$ because $X \in A$ and $B$ is a finite subset of $X$ so we can apply our hypothesis to $X$.

Since $B \in A$ holds for an arbitrary finite subset $B \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr B$, by our hypothesis applied to $\bigcup \mathscr B$ we therefore have $\bigcup \mathscr B \in A$, so $\mathscr B$ has an upper bound in $A$ (namely, $\bigcup \mathscr B$) and we can use Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: I don't understand why $\mathscr{B}$ being a chain implies the existence of $X$. Can you explain that please?

Comment: Because each individual element of $B$ is an element of some member of $\mathscr B$, and because $\mathscr B$ is a chain, its members are all subsets of one another.  So just take the largest of the finitely many members that you've identified, and it will contain *all* elements of $B$.